# Automatically attach and mount EBS volume on new EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

**Scenario**

I currently have an `EC2` instance with a root `EBS` volume attached to it of 30gb and i have some files stored in that `EBS`

If i delete the `EC2` instance and have delete on termination false then `EBS` persists.

**Desired outcome**

I want to provision a new `EC2` (provisioned by auto scaling group) instance such that it uses the old `EBS` volume as its root volume  which was detached as a result of me terminating the old instance

**Note**

I want to have the liberty of choosing OS of newly provisioned `EC2` so creating an `AMI` does not work

Comment: What do you mean by "creating an AMI does not work"? Rather than keeping an EBS volume around for a future instance, you could instead create an AMI of the instance. Then, terminate the instance and delete the EBS volume. Later, when you want to start an instance from the volume, select is as an AMI. It will contain a copy of the data that was on the original EBS volume.

Comment: Sure i'll clarify :) .. when you create an `AMI` that particular `AMI` is restricted by OS you can't migrate from lets say `Amazon linux 2` to just `Amazon linux` when you launch an instance from that `AMI` ... but i want to have the freedom of choice to migrate it when i want,Therefore creating an `AMI` doesn't work

Comment: If you are wanting to provide data to Auto Scaling instances, then you should either use Amazon S3 or Amazon EFS to provide shared data storage for multiple Auto Scaling instances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot directly launch a new Amazon EC2 instance with an existing Amazon EBS volume. Instead, you would need to:

- Launch a new Amazon EC2 instance with a new root volume
- Stop the instance
- Detach the root volume
- Attach the 'old' EBS volume
- Start the instance

Comment: There is a slight issue/limitation of this apporach, I considered it but,

I cant find anyway to automate the `attach` process of my old EBS volume since i want to attach it to  EC2 instance which is launched by an ASG i don't want to manually attach it to every single ec2 instance provisioned by the ASG .... is there any way to automate this ?

Comment: Oh! You didn't say anything about Auto Scaling at first. You should keep your data separate to the operating system.

Comment: i'm accepting this answer can you please check this question aswell ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60123804/how-to-change-the-directory-where-my-docker-image-is-installed-inside-a-containe?noredirect=1#comment106339130_60123804

Answer (score 1):

Storing data in root EBS volume might be a bad idea to start with.

Consider one of the following:

- Mount another EBS volume to the instance to store required data only.
  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-using-volumes.html
  best performance, highest cost/effort, but your application doesn't
  change a bit.
- Create EFS and mount it to your instances. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/mounting-fs.html -
  reasonable effort, minimal if any changes to the application.
- Store data in S3. Ideal from price standpoint; requires changes to the application.