# How to change the directory where my docker image is installed inside a container?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, docker-compose

When i do `df -h` inside my container i get this

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
overlay          30G  1.9G   28G   7% /
tmpfs            64M     0   64M   0% /dev
tmpfs           492M     0  492M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/xvda1       30G  1.9G   28G   7% /etc/hosts
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /dev/shm
:/              8.0E   52M  8.0E   1% /var/www/html
tmpfs           492M     0  492M   0% /proc/acpi
tmpfs           492M     0  492M   0% /proc/scsi
tmpfs           492M     0  492M   0% /sys/firmware
```

**Scenario**

I am running wordpress in my container so when i install it i think it gets installed in either `overlay` or `/dev/xvda1` which is the root volume of my ECS instance which it is running on (EBS 30gb)

**Problem**

What is happening is that when i terminate the `ECS` instance and launch a new one through `autoscaling groups` i lose my installation (obviously since `EBS` volume gets terminated)

**Question**

Is there any way i can change where my wordpress is installed so it persists say maybe a `EFS` mount

Basically i want to change the installation directory so it is not dependent on `EBS` but `EFS`

So when i run the container in any Instance that way my installation persists :)

**Note**

I have already mounted `EFS` on var/www/html so mounting `EFS` on container for persistant storage is not a problem i can simply mount another `EFS` if there is a way to change the installation directory that is where my wordpress gets installed

Any help is highly appreciated thanks :)

Comment: You can use a [bind mount](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/bind-mounts.html) to expose the efs volume to container instances.

Comment: But my `EFS` is mounted on the container instance already... what benefit will i have using bind mount on it again ?

Comment: Why don't you just extract wordpress in /var/www/html?

Comment: I am doing that only all my wordpress files,uploads etc are in /var/www/html and all the data persists there ... but for some reason when i terminate my ECS instance and launch a new instance and run the same container on it i cant access my wordpress site... it wont even load :( that only means one thing that it is getting installed someplace else ?

Comment: I just found `/usr/src/wordpress` wordpress apparently is storing some files here aswell.. which is in `EBS` so could this be causing inconsistency ? when `EBS` terminates ?